# Odoo 15 confirm sale order multi company issue

Tags: odoo

I have a schedule action which will create sale orders for different company depends on certain condition. I set up different behavior for each company when confirm Order. The problem is the schedule action is executed by Administrator because I need to access records from multi company, otherwise, I will get multi company restriction error. However, because of this, it conflicts which the set up when confirm Sale Order, it seems like it doesn't know what is the current company. My question is how to mimic the company widget on the top right of Odoo interface, for example, I want to trigger action_confirm like when I choose a company in the company widget.

In short, the schedule action is executed by user Administrator, but I want to execute certain function in the code under behalf of a specific company due to different set up behavior for  multi company.

Comment: Most of the time i have to use specific company for record creation I use `self.env['sale.order'].sudo().with_context(force_company=company_id).create(values)`
this work's most of the time, but not sure if it will work in your case. Do try though
I tried this in odoo 13, and odoo 15 implementations might be different

Comment: in odoo 15 `force_company` is not used and replaced with `with_company` [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/68145bde6633812f3e55f4563bce2be705aeeddc/odoo/models.py#L5315) 
detailed info related to handling multi-company [odoo-docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/company.html)